# Retrieve data.d.results after REST query

Tags: rest, jquery-ajax

I run a query with REST over two lists. List1 is connected through the field Country with List2.

In the console, I can read the data from the second List but I can't seem to extract it from data.d.results.

```
success: function (data) {
    var items = data.d.results;
    for(var i = 0; i < items.length;i++) {
    message += items[i].Date_x0020_of_x0020_Event + items[i].Column2 + ' <br />';                             
   console.log(items[i].Title);
               }
   $("#div1").html(message);
        console.log(data.d.results);
    },
```

Column2 is the field in List2 connected with Country from List1. It's not retrieving anything there.

[image: console after query]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To extract `data.d.results` you can use for loop as the following:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.d.results.length; i++) 
    {  
     var item = data.d.results[i];  
         console.log(item.Title);
    }
```

For more details Check

- [Join Two Lists Using REST In SharePoint 2013](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/join-two-lists-using-rest-in-sharepoint-2013/)
- [REST query with two lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22954807/rest-query-with-two-lists)

---

**[Update]**

Consider, you have two lists:

- List1.

  - Col1.
- List2.

  - ColA.
  - LookupField to List1.Col1

So to query `List 2` use the below endpoint

```
 /_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('List2')/items?$select=ColA,LookupField/Col1$expand=LookupField
```

To read it use

```
 item.LookupField.Col1
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment,
The Title is easy to get, it's the column2 in the second List.
I think I can retrieve with this:
html += "<tr><td>" + item.Title + "</td><td>" + item.EmployeeName + "</td><td>" + item.Salary + "</td><td>" + item.Dept.Title + "</td><td>" + item.Dept.Code + "</td></tr>"; 

I guess I have to call item.Listname.Field

Comment: You should use `item.LookupField.Col1` , Please Check the updated answer

Comment: Hi Mohammed,
yes I checked your link and I saw it's item.Lookupfield.col1
Cheerz

Comment: @Marco Please don't forget to Mark the answer as accepted in case it helped you :) Thanks!